# Why does the Regex not get applied to the final output?

Tags: javascript, regex, dql, dataview, obsidian

I am trying to apply some regex to some text that is gathered with the Dataview plugin for the note program Obsidian.

I am using the dataview plugin to take some text from multiple notes and copying it as plain text, then I am taking that text and formatting it with regex. The issue I have is that the final output does not get formatted right and I do not know why.

Output example

[image]

The output is supposed to only have "- example" without the duplicate text and the brackets

```js
const inputSentences = [
"- [[Note example 3.md|Note example 3]]",
"- [[Note example 2.md|Note example 2]]",
"- [[Note example 1.md|Note example 1]]"
]


function transformSentence(input) {
  if (typeof input !== 'string') {
    // Handle non-string input, e.g., return input as is or throw an error
    return input;
  }
  const regex = /-\s*\[\[([^|]+)\|[^]]+\]\]/g;
  return input.replace(regex, '- $1');
}

inputSentences.forEach(inputSentence => {
  const outputSentence = transformSentence(inputSentence);
  console.log(outputSentence);
})
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: The `$1` in your replace string asks to use the text that is in capture group one from your scanned result, but you failed to put any capture groups in your regex string.  If you don't know what that means, then you should go and learn about capture groups in regex.  It's a very fundamental concept.  EDIT, sorry I see it now, was it always there?

Comment: The problem is in your code.  Regex101 shows successful scan and replace on your regex string, replacement string, and example.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer No it does not if you chose JavaScript  - had me fooled too

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to escape `]` in your character set:

```
/-\s*\[\[([^|]+)\|[^\]]+\]\]/g
                    ^
```

It seems different regex flavors interpret `[^]]` differently. In JavaScript, this is interpreted as `\^\]` (`^` literal followed by a `]`), but in other flavors/languages like python or PCRE, it is interpreted as `[^\]]` (any character other than `]`). It's better to escape characters like `[`, `]` or `-` within character sets manually to avoid ambiguities.

Using *mplungjan*'s minimal reproducible example:

```js
const inputSentences = [
"- [[Note example 3.md|Note example 3]]",
"- [[Note example 2.md|Note example 2]]",
"- [[Note example 1.md|Note example 1]]"
]


function transformSentence(input) {
  if (typeof input !== 'string') {
    // Handle non-string input, e.g., return input as is or throw an error
    return input;
  }
  const regex = /-\s*\[\[([^|]+)\|[^\]]+\]\]/g;
  return input.replace(regex, '- $1');
}

inputSentences.forEach(inputSentence => {
  const outputSentence = transformSentence(inputSentence);
  console.log(outputSentence);
})
```

Comment: Well spotted. The regex works in regex101 unless you choose JavaScript

Comment: @mplungjan I also appreciate that regex101 can reflect these quirks among different languages accurately, despite everything being simulated in JavaScript. Otherwise I would have my hair pulled out to figure out what is actually happening.

Comment: The data is pulled from a async api from the dataview plugin. Not sure how that is usually handled but it seems to skip the regex for some reason. Here is the documentation: https://blacksmithgu.github.io/obsidian-dataview/api/code-reference/ someone seems to have modified the original code in the original message. I am quite new to stackoverflow so i do not know why this is.

Comment: That's quite odd, are you sure that `input` is a typeof `string` and has the exacly the format you're expecting? (No weird white spaces, invisible characters anywhere)